# Facebook APP User ID

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I created a php script, using a standard php example on how to get user information (user id and name) with PHP Facebook SDK.

I also created 2 facebook apps (one before one month and a second today).
When I use the first app with my code, I get back the right `Facebook User ID` but when I use the second app I get back something like this `10152375153XXXXX` instead of my id.

Both of these apps have the same settings.

Has FB changed something in the new apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 4/30/2014 and the launch of the Graph API version 2.0, applications will receive what is called an "app-scoped" id instead of the canonical Facebook user id.  This is a benefit to users as less information is being provided to app developers and they are more in control.  It also stops different apps (not owned by the same developer) from associating users and their data.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.0